# How to find if a conversation between two users exists (in mySQL query)

Tags: mysql, messaging

I want to find if a conversation between one user and others exists and from there select only the name of the other participant(s) (in this case, the user(s) that is/are not authenticated, that have chatted with authenticated user).

**So, lets say that user `1` has chatted with user `5` and `6`, how do I find the users user `1` has had a conversation with, regardless of whether he started it or the others did?** The `messaging` table would look something like this

```
 Columns:  | id | fromId | toId | msg |
             0    1        5      'hi'
             1    5        1      '..'
             3    1        6      '!'
             4    6        1      '?'
             5    1        5      '#'
```

I wound only need the name of each user once, so the query for this should result in (for user `1`):

```
5, 6
```

I have this so far:

```
    SELECT * FROM `messaging`
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM messaging
    WHERE `toId` = 1
    ORDER BY id DESC) a
    on (messaging.id=a.id)
    GROUP BY messaging.fromUser;
```

But of course, this only returns a result if the other user sent a message to the authenticated user, and not vice versa. How can I add the other scenario to this query? So that it also finds the conversations where `fromId = 1` and fetches `toId`?

I realize I probably couldn't explain this very well, but I hope it's clear. My native language is not english and I suck a mySQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Write a query that finds the conversations he started, another query that finds the conversations he received, and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT fromId AS userId FROM messaging
  WHERE toId = 1
UNION
Select toId AS userId FROM messaging
  WHERE fromId = 1;
```

Comment: Oh, it was a simple matter. Thanks.